# Not able to refactor UIViewController to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a UIViewController that I segue to from multiple places in my app. I am not able to refactor that UIViewController from the main story board to its own storyboard. When I select UIViewController and then Editor->Refactor to storyboard a copy of the new storybaord is created in Base.lproj but I don't see that in the left hand project navigation in Xcode and the UIviewcontroller is still showing in the Main.storyboard.

I am using Xcode 9.2

Comment: Do you want to navigate from ViewController in One Storyboard to ViewController in another storyboard using segue ?

Comment: hi Sagar, i am trying to refactor a UIViewcontroller in main story board in to a new storyboard of its own. I am trying to do this by selecting the UIViewcontroller and then Editor -> Refactor to storyboard

Comment: Same problem here but with a small difference, my new storyboard appear but on the very top of the view hierarchy, even on top than the x-code project file. The storyboard cannot be dragged/moved to any folder. If I do it, then a new instance is copied instead of to move. Playing around with it, I discovered a bug. If I right click on the new storyboard ->create a new group with selected file, x-code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the fix is just to wait for few mins after you click on Editor->Refactor to storyboard for the new story board to show up under the left project panel. Not sure if its an Xcode bug but thats what fixed it.